# Why can't I use my local variable despite already returning it?

Tags: python, variables

It says I haven't defined the variable even though the code that does that is literally right above it, the error message appears:

*"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 55, in 
if kategoribmi == "underweight":
NameError: name 'kategoribmi' is not defined"*

```
    if kelas == "('15', 'P')":
      if bmi > 28.2:
        kategoribmi = "obese"
      elif bmi >= 23.6 < 28.2:
        kategoribmi = "overweight"
      elif bmi <= 15.8:
        kategoribmi = "underweight"
      else:
        kategoribmi = "ideal"


    if kategoribmi == "underweight":
      underweight()
    elif kategoribmi == "overweight":
      overweight()
    elif kategoribmi == "obese":
      obese()
    else:
      ideal()
```

I'm really unsure what to do here, I've tried looking up how to fix this but I'm still unclear.

Comment: I don't see any `return` statement, despite the question title.

Comment: If `kelas` is not equal to `"('15', 'P')"`, `kategoribmi` won't be defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens  because when the compiler checks your code, it cannot be sure whether the execution will reach `kategoribmi = "something"`. If the `if` statement where you assign a value to `kategoribmi` will not be true at execution, the variable will not be assigned. And whether this will be the case or not, cannot be known at compile time.

The simple solution to this is to assign a default value to `kategoribmi` before the first set of `if` statements, like so:

```
kategoribmi = ""

if kelas == "('15', 'P')":
    if bmi > 28.2:
        kategoribmi = "obese"
    elif bmi >= 23.6 < 28.2:
        kategoribmi = "overweight"
    elif bmi <= 15.8:
        kategoribmi = "underweight"
    else:
        kategoribmi = "ideal"

if kategoribmi == "underweight":
    underweight()
elif kategoribmi == "overweight":
    overweight()
elif kategoribmi == "obese":
    obese()
else:
    ideal()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit incomplete, perhaps it is inside a function? Is there a previous condition that has to evaluate to `True`? For better help you should provide more code. Are you sure your code can evaluate to `True` for the condition `if kelas == "('15', 'P')"` every time you run it?. On a side note, you are leaving out the value 28.2

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If the variable `kelas` is not equal to the string `"('15', 'P')"`, for example if it is a tuple `('15', 'P')` instead of a string, or if it is any other value like `"anything"`, the code jumps right to the line `if kategoribmi == "underweight"`, not executing the ones inside the if statement.

I don't know what you are trying to do, but one of the possible solutions is to increase the bottom part's indentation so that it is inside the if statement above: (if you intend it to only be run when `kelas=="('15', 'P')"`.

```
    if kelas == "('15', 'P')":
        if bmi > 28.2:
            kategoribmi = "obese"
        elif bmi >= 23.6 < 28.2:
            kategoribmi = "overweight"
        elif bmi <= 15.8:
            kategoribmi = "underweight"
        else:
            kategoribmi = "ideal"



        if kategoribmi == "underweight":
            underweight()
        elif kategoribmi == "overweight":
            overweight()
        elif kategoribmi == "obese":
            obese()
        else:
            ideal()
```

Another solution is to change the `kelas=="('15', 'P')"` to `kelas==('15', 'P')`. Maybe you were trying to compare the `kelas` as a tuple. Anyways, without the complete minimum reproducible code, we cannot provide much for you.